# MAPK signalling pathway initial conditions

Tags: cell-biology

I would like to know the initial conditions and locations of the chemical reagents in the MAPK cascasde.

I'm going to plug this information into a reaction diffusion simulation.

From reading various papers I have gleaned the following:

```
[MKKK]total = 100nm; [MKK]total = 300nm; [MAPK]total = 300nm

MKKK]total = [MKKK] + [MKKK-P]
[MKK]total = [MKK] + [MKK-P] + [MKK-PP]
[MAPK]total = [MAPK] + [MAPK-P] + [MAPK-PP]

Ras-GTP seems to have an initial concentration of 30 nM and seems to start at the nucleus.

ppMAPK seems to have an initial concentration of 0.
```

I can't figure out where the rest of the reagents start and what thier concentrations are. People always seem to miss this out from their work...

Thanks

Comment: This is probably because it is not important for most people. I did work in this field and it was interesting that proof *that* the signal came down the cascade (and via which) but not how the concentration were.

Comment: @Chris what do you advise doing? Should I make the other reagents equally distributed throughout the system? Should I just make up concentrations?